# Have we seen a dyad in the Force before?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-rise-of-skywalker

In *The Rise of Skywalker* we find out that the connection between Rey and Kylo is a bit more than what we first though. They form a dyad in the Force: a pairing of two physical beings that become one in the Force.

> **Kylo Ren:** My mother was the daughter of Vader. Your father was the son of the Emperor. What Palpatine doesn’t know is we’re a dyad in the Force way. Two that are one. We’ll kill him together and take the throne.
>
> <sub>*The Rise of Skywalker*</sub>

Later on we learn of a prophecy about this dyad in the Force that was about restoring Emperor Palpatine to his former self.

> **Emperor Palpatine:** The life force of your bond, a dyad in the Force. A power like life itself. Unseen for generations. And now, the power of two restores the one true Emperor.
>
> <sub>*The Rise of Skywalker*</sub>

What is interesting about this though is that Palpatine says *"Unseen for generations"* which indicates it has been seen before.

**Do we know when a dyad in the Force has shown up before?** If not have we seen any other Force-bonds similar to Rey and Kylo that could have been a dyad but it just wasn't named yet? (*The Rise of Skywalker* and its *Visual Dictionary* seem to be the first time it was identified as a dyad in the Force).

---

Legends answers are acceptable but I am mainly looking for canon answers.

Comment: The two characters mentioned are deeply untrustworthy, and the lines quoted are in the context of manipulation and persuading someone to take their side. Do we even know that Force Dyads are a thing, from a reliable source?

Comment: @GrahamLee Did you watch the film? What Rey and Kylo can do _is_ the reliable source.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Jedi Exile Meetra Surik and Kreia had a particularly strong Force-Bond in the second Knights of the Old Republic game, which has many of the same features as the bond between Kylo and Rey seems to have.

Across vast distances, Kreia was able to contact Meetra and lecture her on whatever it was she was doing at that time, much like the way Kylo and Rey seem to be able to talk to one-another over large distances.

They never showed the ability to teleport objects, though, so if this was a Dyad or not is hard to tell, especially because a Dyad is something new that was made up for the new trilogy as a plot device to allow the characters to communicate without coming physically face-to-face.

> It was always through the demands of the story. With the Force connections between Rey and Kylo I thought, “OK, I need to get these two talking. But if I put them face to face they’re going to either fight, or one of them has to be tied up” — [Interview](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment/movies/la-et-mn-star-wars-last-jedi-spoilers-20171218-htmlstory.html)

So odds are any link you can find to old stories with a Force-Bond that feels like a Dyad in the Force is mostly just a coincidence, considering Rian Johnson made up the connection between Rey and Kylo as a plot convenience.

Comment: Beat me to it, I was gonna mention Revan and Bastilla from the first game

Answer (score 1):

A canon example of a [force dyad](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_dyad) might be **Luke & Leia** themselves. Even in the original trilogy, they are able to communicate, as when [Leia rescues Luke](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NottMSxCPHg) from Cloud City.

> Luke: *Leia. Hear Me.*
> Leia: *Luke.  We've got to go back...*

Sure, they're not able chit-chat or send objects across the gulf (yet) as they're just starting out! Clearly, Luke has been able to communicate his location, which I think it is safe to assume that Leia has actually seen even though this is not revealed on screen.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this or is it simply your own opinion?

Comment: I rather thought it was obvious from the film, the evidence of which is linked in the answer --- the whole "Leia, Leia, hear me" thing. If it wasn't clear, I added the link to the definition: *Physically, they were two separate individuals, but in the Force they were one. This form of connection made it possible for the bonded individuals to communicate with each other across great distances.* Let's not forget: that movie was made 30 to 40 years ago, before this ever became a named concept. Kind of cool that the Ren~Kylo thing was foreshadowed by an earlier dyad!

Comment: They're not really communicating over great distances though, are they? Leia is almost within shouting distance.

Answer (score -1):

I am going out on a limb here but I Truly think force bonds and a Dyad in the force are different. Force bonds are between two force sensitive, users, one being stronger in the force than the other, who can communicate over great distance, like Luke and Leia, or just feel the presence of the other such as Finn and Rey. They couldn’t see each other or transport objects both ways.
The force Dyad, Two that are one, on the other hand was a much stronger in that the connection was between two force sensitive users Who were equals in their force abilities. And like the emperor said it was a  “life force” bond, stronger than life itself. Ben and Rey had a life Connection through their bond Which grew stronger every time they were together. While a regular force bond can grow as the force users Grow, it will never become a life bond or Dyad.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence for this or is it simply your own opinion?

Comment: Welcome to the Scifi stackexchange! Could you give any references to back up what you are saying?

Answer (score -2):

Luke and Leia are force dyads.  Not only can they sense each other... Leia sensing Luke in distress in Empire.  But in The Last Jedi, Luke connects and transfers Han's dice.  This lasts long enough for Kylo Ren/Ben to pick it up.  At that point, it disappears.

Personal speculation, the object gets "reset" into it's original space the moment one or both halves of the dyad die.  That would explain why the dice disappears at the same time that Luke dies.

Kylo Ren, figures this out and realizes that he and Rey are a dyad as well. This is why he knows that he can manipulate Rey's physical space while not present there physically.  Hence the scene where he grabs the necklace.  He's already seen what a force dyad can do because he found his father's dice.

Further personal speculation, Force Dyads can travel long distance as a result of their connection.  The greater the connection, the greater the power of the two force users, the greater the chances that one can "teleport" to the other half's location.  (of course, this would be in novelizations and further Star Wars media.  But I'd like to think this is possible.)

BTW - even more personal speculation - force dyads must be dark/light.  It's like a battery.  Positive and Negative to push the force between the two "magnetic" poles.  Luke is quite obviously a dark sensitive force user whereas Leia is a light sensitive force user.  Luke is prone to anger and violence and fear.  Leia is not as prone to fear as her twin brother.

I like the idea of a force dyad.  It lends itself into the balance magic system of Star Wars.

Comment: This seems very speculative, especially the part about Luke being Dark.  I think this would be a stronger answer if you took the purely speculative bits (the 4th and 5th paragraphs) out.

Comment: Hence the fact that I added the word "speculation"...  Look at the movies.  Leia is sugar and spice and everything nice.  It's Luke that is constantly struggling with his darkness.  Leia controls her emotions.  Luke is very much like Anakin.